# How to Add a Request Header in an Integration Test For an API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am creating an integration test for an API controller that requires custom header information in the request.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromQuery] string param1, [FromQuery] string param2)
{
    …
    var id = Request.Headers["X-Id1"].ToString();
    var id2 = Request.Headers["X-Id2"].ToString();
    … 
}
```

How can I add this request headers in my integration test? I got stuck at the code below because `_controller.ControllerContext` is of type `ControllerContext` and I cannot convert an `HttpControllerContext` object to it. The error message is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext'`

**INTEGRATION TEST**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Headers.Add("X-Id1", "1");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Id2", "2");

    var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext();
    controllerContext.Request = request;

    _controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext; // Error message shows here.
    _controller.Delete("a", "b");

    // Assertion here.
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Please state your error message ? From your code, you already have the headers added. What's the issue ?

Comment: @HariHaran: the error message is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext'.`

Comment: You need to create the object of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext` and assign to `controllerContext.Request`

Comment: But that's the problem, `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request` is read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Id1"] = "1";
_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Id2"] = "2";
```